# Error when Creating New Item in datasource with relationship

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a ONE to MANY relationship setup between two datasources (longer explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46801400/trying-to-total-columns-for-relation-datasource)).

I am intermittently getting errors when trying to create or edit an item in the non-owner datasource.

```
Thu Oct 19 11:59:20 GMT-700 2017
Drive Table internal error. Please try again. Caused by: Execution Failed. More information: Internal error encountered.. (HTTP status code: unknown) Error: Drive Table internal error. Please try again.

Thu Oct 19 11:59:20 GMT-700 2017
Creating new record: (Error) : Drive Table internal error. Please try again.
at PORequests.Panel13.Panel18.Add_Item.onClick:1:19

Thu Oct 19 11:59:20 GMT-700 2017
Creating new record failed.
```

When I looked at the server logs I see:

```
{
 insertId:  "13ovnchfxwxsqq"  
 labels: {
  script.googleapis.com/process_id:  "EAEA1GOwsdCh8YjD5KVVeBwT21xln0G3WFk4ULblcC0zX8_PML2UzR0o6WSPEhKBCgXa9SY_g6dxTqLJKMqQXk0UrIJW6en9rymo8OEBcw0X4tv4pLZeSxFNgRbInWHBJiegZM4WyjaPBqw1q"   
  script.googleapis.com/project_key:  "MBTigw5qnbrHScnjNatBP5Rs3AwaeoTZn"   
  script.googleapis.com/user_key:  "AEiMU4fv5flw4TblvkAxoOl6zKB5363j63bCyxicf/bJJXwtBFLZYGEBRLOkH+Z68eLnXiHPnR98"   
 }
 logName:  "projects/project-id-8108427532903699662/logs/script.googleapis.com%2Fconsole_logs"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2017-10-19T18:59:21.737166790Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   function_name:  "__appmakerGlobalScriptWrapper"    
   invocation_type:  "web app"    
   project_id:  "project-id-8108427532903699662"    
  }
  type:  "app_script_function"   
 }
 severity:  "ERROR"  
 textPayload:  "Drive Table internal error. Please try again. 
Caused by: Execution Failed. More information: Internal error encountered.. (HTTP status code: unknown)
Error: Drive Table internal error. Please try again. "  
 timestamp:  "2017-10-19T18:59:20.729Z"  
}
```

Anyone else seen this issue? Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?